# How to access file system using Intel XDK app?

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems, html5-filesystem, intel-xdk

I am creating an app using Intel XDK, in HTML5 and javascript, and write some of the data fed by user to the local file system. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what actually you trying to to.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel XDK supports Cordova 2.9.0 at the time of this writing. See this thread on the XDK forum for a link and a few hints:

[https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=4892&p=18121&hilit=local+filesystem#p18121](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=4892&p=18121&hilit=local%20filesystem#p18121)

Comment: An example of how to do that would be nice

Answer (score 0):

You may have solved the problem. this is for people who are new and run into this thread. you can use [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to manage with file system.